# Spring form model attribute class with another object

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, model

I work with Spring MVC and JSP. I want to input the class product using a form. Class Product has another object Catalog

Product class

```
public class Product {
    private int productId;
    private Catalog catalog;
    private String sku;
    private String productName;
    private int availableQuantity;
    private String uom;

    public Product() {

    }
```

Catalog is

```
public class Catalog {

 protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Catalog.class.getName());

private int catalogId;
private String catalogName;
private List<Product> products= new ArrayList<Product>();

public Catalog() {

}
```

I created a modelAttribute product in the controller

```
model.addAttribute(new Product());
 return "product/addProduct";
```

I want to input the catalog id using a dropdown. This dropdown is

```
<tr> 
            <th><label for="catalog_id">Catalog id:</label></th>
            <td><sf:select path="catalog" items="${catalogList}" />

            </td> 
        </tr>
```

The jsp is:

```
 <sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="product">
<table border="0">
    <tr> 
        <th><label for="catalog_id">Catalog id:</label></th>
        <td><sf:select path="catalog" items="${catalogList}" />

        </td> 
    </tr> 

    <tr> 
        <th><label for="product_name">Product Name:</label></th>
        <td><sf:input path="productName" size="128" id="product_name" /><br/>
            <sf:errors path="productName" cssClass="error" /> 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <th><label for="product_sku">Product sku:</label></th>
        <td><sf:input path="sku" size="32" id="product_sku" /><br/>
            <sf:errors path="sku" cssClass="error" /> 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <th><label for="product_availablequantity">Available Quantity:</label></th>
        <td><sf:input path="availableQuantity"  id="product_availablequantity" /><br/>
            <sf:errors path="availableQuantity" cssClass="error" /> 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <th><label for="product_unitofmeasure">Unit of measure:</label></th>
        <td><sf:input path="uom"  size="32"  id="product_unitofmeasure" /><br/>
            <sf:errors path="uom" cssClass="error" /> 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</sf:form>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I have to define the path product.catalog.catalogId?